# Having a issue to solve condition number in python

Tags: python, numpy, math

```
def createA(self, n):
    """ this method creates a nxn coefficient """



def main():
    # "points_of_failure_in_L :  point x = L in every n"


    for i in range(0, 12):
        n = 20 * (2**i)

        points_of_failure_in_L = np.abs(brett.fasit_y(n) - brett.finn_y(n))[n - 1]
        condition_Number_A = np.linalg.cond(brett.createA(n).toarray())
        print(n, points_of_failure_in_L, "\t", "condition", condition_Number_A)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to compare with the condition number of A for those
different values ​​of n.
I having problem with: `points_of_failure_in_L=np.linalg.cond(brett.createA(n).toarray())`

prints out
`20 8.144526719711109e-16    condition 282259.21106512705
40 7.64151112178646e-15      condition 4389447.783996872
80 3.42975431041892e-14      condition 69191086.43073456
160 8.638996094011142e-14    condition 1098636697.701042
320 3.9277543890936517e-13   condition 17510431736.872536
640 7.368569980798021e-12    condition 279623343789.7353
1280 9.507172970768204e-11   condition 4469444304850.158
2560 3.463085792795601e-10   condition 71481983012454.66
5120 2.5468403313525705e-11      condition 1139844383400946.2
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`

The condition numbers can't be right?!
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? :)

Comment: Hi Eirik, I don't think your code is reproducible. What is `brett`?

Comment: Brett (Norwegian language) is the same as Board.  The answer I got was correct. :)